Highest weight root of $E_6$, explicitly
According to Wikipedia, there is a 6-dimensional subspace in $\mathbb{R}^{9}$ giving a nice symmetric basis for the root system of $E_6$. Especially, six simple roots are
$$
\alpha_1 = (0, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0; 0, 1, -1) \\
\alpha_2 = (0, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0;, 1, -1, 0) \\
\alpha_3 = (0, 0, 0; 0, 1, -1; 0, 0, 0) \\
\alpha_4 = (0, 0, 0; 1, -1, 0; 0, 0, 0) \\
\alpha_5 = (0, 1, -1; 0, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0) \\
\alpha_6 = \frac{1}{3}(1,-2,1;-2,1,1;-2,1,1)
$$
which can be placed on the $E_6$ Dynkin diagram as
$$
\begin{align*}&\alpha_5 \\
&\,\,| \\
\alpha_1 - \alpha_2 - \,&\alpha_6 - \alpha_4 - \alpha_3
\end{align*}
$$
Now, I wonder how we can express the highest weight of the adjoint representation of $E_6$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of $\alpha_i$'s. Or, if possible, any other nice basis that can answer the same question might be enough (especially with references). Thanks in advance.

It is a standard fact that if the highest root $\theta$ of a simply-laced Lie algebra is written as a linear combination of simple roots $ \theta = \sum_{i \in I} a_i\alpha_i$ then if you number the vertices of the Dynkin diagram accordingly, twice the coefficient $a_i$ on a vertex is equal to the sum of the $a_j$ on adjacent vertices, except at one node, which is the node to which the affine vertex is attached.
Equivalently, in terms of the affine diagram, the purely imaginary root $\delta$ is given by $\delta = \sum_{i \in \hat{I}}a_i \alpha_i = \alpha_0 + \theta$ where $\theta$ is the highest root, and $\hat{C}(\mathbf a)=0$ where $\hat{C}$ is the affine Cartan matrix.
For $E_6$ this gives:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
@. @. 1 @. @.\\
@. @. @VVV @. @.\\
@. @. 2 @. @. \\
@. @. @VVV @. @.\\
1 @>>> 2 @>>> 3 @<<< 2 @<<< 1
\end{CD}
$$
That is, $\theta = \alpha_1+\alpha_3 + 2(\alpha_2+ \alpha_4+ \alpha_5) + 3 \alpha_6$.

Thank you! I didn't aware of this, do you have any (standard) reference that mentions this? I couldn't find this on Humphrey's or Hall's (possibly I missed).

Stated in terms of the affine diagram, it should be in Kac's book on infinite-dimensional Lie algebras. It is also discussed in Carter's book on Lie algebras of finite and affine type I think?

I found on Kac's book - thank you so much!

Humphreys has no need for this result on the f.d. Lie algebra side :-) I encountered it when researching representations of algebraic groups in positive characteristic (when you also run into the affine Weyl groups). +1, of course.
